# How are non integer images represented?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, precision

**Intro**

To the computer, digital grayscale images are represented as integer matrices where the maximim number (which is dependent on the integer precision) represents black an 0 is white.

[image]

Here is a representation of an image which for integers, and when cast to floats.

[image]

```
int
array([[6, 1, 1, 0, 6, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 7, 5, 2],
       [0, 4, 6, 6, 3, 4],
       [1, 1, 2, 6, 7, 0],
       [3, 6, 6, 5, 5, 3]])

float
array([[ 6.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  6.,  4.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  7.,  5.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  4.,  6.,  6.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  2.,  6.,  7.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  6.,  6.,  5.,  5.,  3.]])
```

**Question**

I've been working with svd, and as a result, a get an image whose matrix representation consists of floats. It gets printed fine with `imshow` from matplotlib.

How does the 'brightness to value' mapping works when the grayscale image values are floats?

Comment: Can you not determine this fairly easily for yourself by creating an image with a mixture of black / white / some middle shade of grey?

Comment: @Vicky No, not really. I've updated the question based on your comment. Why isn't the representation different, shouldn't the  minimal brightness step change?

Comment: It looks like this is just how imshow() works, I'll post an answer in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.weizmann.ac.il/matlab/toolbox/images/imshow.html

> imshow(I,n) displays the intensity image I with n discrete levels of
>   gray. If you omit n, imshow uses 256 gray levels on 24-bit displays,
>   or 64 gray levels on other systems.
>
> imshow(I,[low high]) displays I as a grayscale intensity image,
>   specifying the data range for I. The value low (and any value less
>   than low) displays as black, the value high (and any value greater
>   than high) displays as white, and values in between display as
>   intermediate shades of gray. imshow uses the default number of gray
>   levels. If you use an empty matrix ([]) for [low high], imshow uses
>   [min(I(:)) max(I(:))]; the minimum value in I displays as black, and
>   the maximum value displays as white.
>
> imshow(BW) displays the binary image BW. Values of 0 display as black,
>   and values of 1 display as white.

So it depends how you are calling imshow() as to how it interprets the image for display. If you are calling it with an empty matrix for [low,high] it will just use whatever the max and min values in the array are.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I am, however using the version from `matplotlib`, a python plotting library. But that answered my question. It basically always gets discretized and using floats end up as an overhead once the image processing is finished.

Answer (score 1):

`matplotlib` maps values to colors using the `colormap` [(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap) class (and it's sub-classes) and the `Normalize` [(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.Normalize) class (and it's sub-classes).  The basic idea is that `normalize` converts what ever input you give it to floats in the range of `[0, 1]`. There are a variety of linear and non-linear ways to do this (implementing gamma correction for example)  The `colormap` class then coverts scalars in the range `[0, 1]` -> `rgb` values, and can do that by any mapping you want [(gallery)](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps)